# How can root user create file/directory unwritable for itself?

Tags: linux, permissions, filesystems

Normal users can `chmod` files to make them unaccessible like

```
evgeniy@ubuntu:~$ touch test
evgeniy@ubuntu:~$ chmod 444 test
evgeniy@ubuntu:~$ echo 'test' > test
bash: test: Permission denied
```

Can something like this be simulated for the root user?

Comment: I hope not, or I'm sure to do it.

Comment: Go ahead and check the @danlefree's answer ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`chattr +i *` will prevent even the root account from making changes to files in the directory (until `chattr -i *` is run).

Per Slartibartfast's comments, a few things you should know about [chattr](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chattr) and the immutable attribute:

1. The *immutable* bit will prevent a file from being deleted, renamed, linked to, or written to; use `lsattr` to display attributes in much the same way `ls` displays ownership and permissions
2. You can prevent the immutable bit from being unset (even by root) by changing the `CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE` flag - to do so you'll want to install [libcap](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/security/linux-privs/), but it's only fair warning that capabilities are poorly documented (at best)

Comment: It is worth mentioning for purposes of helping people find this answer that chattr +i makes the file immutable.

Answer (score 5):

SELinux can be used to mark a file as unwriteable by root in the current domain and user role.

Comment: Providing an example would be great

Comment: SELinux must be considered as untrustworthy as OpenSSL with the Heartbleed and RNG patches that came from the same source. (Namely the NSA.)
There are alternatives though. The common name for such solutions is “RBAC” (role-based access-control) in specific or “MAC” (mandatory access control) in general.